# how can i take a column from the database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

mysql_fetch_array returns my rows but I want the colunms, for example :

```
    $bilgi= mysql_query("SELECT age,wname,slid,sex,c_name FROM user ");
    //echo mysql_errno($con).":".mysql_error($con)."\n";
    while($sutun= mysql_fetch_array($bilgi))
    {

        echo $sutun["age"]." ";
        echo $sutun["wname"]." ";
        echo $sutun["sex"]." ";     
        echo $sutun["slid"]." ";
        echo $sutun["c_name"]."\n"; 

    }
```

this return me rows i want it to return colonms any idea?

Comment: What do you mean "colonms?" Columns? The column names are listed as you had to specifically point them out in the query. What is your question?

Comment: i want to take forexample only the first colonm not the rest or the third colonm when i write $sutun["age"]; it gives me age row all the ages i want it to give me something like "50 happy male 60 France" this is 1 tuple in my database i just want this; not rows

Comment: I'm sorry - I simply cannot understand your English.

Comment: So you only wan't ONE row, not one column. Is there a primary key, a field that you can use to identify your row?

Comment: Yes i want only 1 row damn sorry for wrong english i only want 1 row my fault sorry @kyle Boddy

Comment: i have id in my table that is primary key

Comment: Then, as cularis pointed out, you need to modify your query to return only one row. Use a primary key or ID to identify which row you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$bilgi= mysql_query("SELECT age,wname,slid,sex,c_name FROM user LIMIT 1");
```

Would only return one row, but I don't think this is what you want?
You need a primary key and use that in a WHERE clause to identify the row you need.

```
$bilgi= mysql_query("SELECT age,wname,slid,sex,c_name FROM user WHERE id=1");
```

`id` being the primary key to identify a row.

Comment: Deleted my answer and +1'd this.